# gernerate XML file format from oracle Table

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I want a XML file format as below.

XML should look like below:-

```
<server name="Server123">
<schema name="cwmm">
<table name="ACC" rows="1000000"/>
<table name="KEYS" rows="1000000"/>
</schema>
<schema name="CWM1610">
<table name="ACC" rows="1000000"/>
<table name="KEYS" rows="1000000"/>
</schema>
```

what, I have done is created a temporary table called TAB_INFO with the information about the table_owner, tables and their rows. so please help in achieving the above format. I was thinking to use the package dbms_xmlgen but I am clueless how to achieve the above.

Table has columns as below:-

```
owner
table_name
num_rows
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: "I was thing to use the package dbms_xmlgen but I am clueless how to achieve the above." So read the doc, try something and if it doesn't work, post a specific question.

Comment: pls. show us wht you have tried ?

Comment: I suggest using another programming language to convert your query results to xml.

Comment: @DanBracuk Why use another language when Oracle can easily do the transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db691/6)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TAB_INFO (owner, table_name, num_rows ) AS
SELECT 'cwmm',    'ACC',  1000000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'cwmm',    'KEYS', 1000000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CWM1610', 'ACC',  1000000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CWM1610', 'KEYS', 1000000 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT XMLElement(
         "server",
         XMLAttributes( 'Server123' AS "name" ),
         XMLAGG( schema )
       ).getClobVal() AS xml
FROM   (
  SELECT XMLElement(
           "schema",
           XMLAttributes( owner AS "name" ),
           XMLAgg(
             XMLElement(
               "table",
               XMLAttributes(
                 table_name AS "name",
                 num_rows AS "rows"
               )
             )
           )
         ) AS schema
  FROM   tab_info
  GROUP BY owner
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db691/6/0)**:

```
|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   XML |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| <server name="Server123"><schema name="CWM1610"><table name="ACC" rows="1000000"></table><table name="KEYS" rows="1000000"></table></schema><schema name="cwmm"><table name="ACC" rows="1000000"></table><table name="KEYS" rows="1000000"></table></schema></server> |
```